# How to obtain the minimal covering of a circle with H3 hexagons?

Tags: spherical-geometry, h3, dggs

Given an EPSG:4326 `lon,lat` coordinate pair, and a radius `r` in meters, I want to find the smallest set of H3 hexagons at resolution `res` that completely covers the circle centered at `lon,lat` with radius `r`.

The H3 library has a [`polygon_to_cells`](https://uber.github.io/h3-py/api_reference.html#h3.polygon_to_cells) function that returns the set of H3 cells with their center points inside a given polygon.

My current strategy (in Python because that's what I happen to be using) is to approximate a circle with a polygon, by "stepping" through forward azimuths from 0 to 360 degrees and computing the point that is `r` distance away at each forward azimuth value. I am then using the `polygon_to_cells` function on that circle-approximating polygon.

Based on some un-rigorous geometric intuition, it seems like if I set the buffer size to `r + (2 × res)`, then I should be able to cover every point in the original circle of radius `r` with an H3 cell. If I want to find the "minimum" covering set, I can then loop over the resulting list of H3 cells and prune away any that do not intersect the original (approximated) circle.

However this approach seems *very* ad-hoc and unprincipled. Is there some better algorithm I can use?

Edit: It looks like H3 uses spherical coordinates with the WGS84 authalic radius ([source](https://h3geo.org/docs/core-library/overview/)), in case that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to calculate your polygon as you are now (though I'd probably use a popular geometry library like Shapely rather than my own circle buffering algorithm), but only with a buffer of `r`. Then use `h3.grid_ring` with `k = 1`, and calculate the intersection of the sets. This isn't very efficient unless you can first limit this to cells that don't already have 6 neighbours (which is possible to work out) or perhaps use grid distance from the cell at the centre as information for how to limit the computation.

A slight frame challenge response might be that if you really care about strict coverage of the circle, then a DGGS might not be the appropriate tool. The basic idea is to approximate geographic objects, in the same way a digital recording of an analogue wave only approximates the original, continuous sound. If you need higher fidelity, you should increase the cell resolution.

Comment: It turns out that this is how the h3ronpy library does it internally. Thanks! In my case the problem was not a matter of fidelity but of exhaustiveness. For example using H3 index to coarsely filter for matching polygons, followed by a precise intersection check on the filtered data.